# DISNAKE | Как создать параметр в слеш команде с выбором?

Tags: python, бот, discord, disnake

Хочу создать команду с подобным выбором как на картинке.
У меня бот на disnake [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Помог? Поставьте галочку

Answer (score 0):

Это делается так:

```
@bot.slash_command(name='тест', description='тест')
async def test0(ctx, test1:  Option(name='test', description='testing', type=str, required=True, choices=['1', '2', '3', '4'])):
    pass
```

Всего лишь добавляем аргумент `choices`